# How to define EF code-first tri-way FK relationship? (parent with two related children)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm not sure how to express precisely what my problem is, so I'll just dive into what I have done and describe the problem as it occurs. Actual question is at the end of the post.

I'm using EF 4.3 with code-first, and have this general Category entity for organizing various types of content:

```
public enum ContentType { Articles, Videos };

public class Category
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long? ParentCategoryID { get; set; }

    internal int ContentTypeValue { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }

    public ContentType ContentType
    {
        get { return (ContentType) ContentTypeValue; }
        set { ContentTypeValue = (int) value; }
    }
}
```

This is mapped to the database using the following definitions (I'm using a helper class, but Map simply refers to the concrete model builder for the entity):

```
Map.Property( e => e.ContentTypeValue ).IsRequired().HasColumnName( "ContentType" );
Map.Property( e => e.Title ).IsRequired().HasMaxLength( 200 );

Map.HasOptional( e => e.ParentCategory ).WithMany( r => r.ChildCategories ).HasForeignKey( e => e.ParentCategoryID ).WillCascadeOnDelete( false );
```

Note that Category does not provide references to other entity types (except itself).

Then I added an Article entity and the mapping for it:

```
public class Article
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long CategoryID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

Map.Property( e => e.Title ).IsRequired().HasMaxLength( 50 );
Map.Property( e => e.Body ).IsRequired().HasMaxLength( 4000 );
Map.HasRequired( e => e.Category ).WithMany().HasForeignKey( e => e.CategoryID ).WillCascadeOnDelete( false );
```

This works fine and creates an Article table with PK(ID) and FK(CategoryID) to the Category table.

Next step was to add a similar entity and mapping definition for Video, which also worked as expected.

```
public class Video
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long CategoryID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

Map.Property( e => e.Title ).IsRequired().HasMaxLength( 50 );
Map.Property( e => e.FileName ).IsRequired().HasMaxLength( 200 );
Map.HasRequired( e => e.Category ).WithMany().HasForeignKey( e => e.CategoryID ).WillCascadeOnDelete( false );
```

However, now I would like for Article to have a direct reference to a particular Video (regardless of which category any of them is in), so in essence a 1:1 (required:optional) reference between the two.

```
public class Article // broken
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long CategoryID { get; set; }
    public long? VideoID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Video Video { get; set; }
}
```

And to map the class I'd use the following:

```
Map.Property( e => e.Title ).IsRequired().HasMaxLength( 50 );
Map.Property( e => e.Body ).IsRequired().HasMaxLength( 4000 );
Map.HasRequired( e => e.Category ).WithMany().HasForeignKey( e => e.CategoryID ).WillCascadeOnDelete( false );
Map.HasOptional( e => e.Video ).WithMany().HasForeignKey( e => e.VideoID ).WillCascadeOnDelete( false );
```

As soon as I add such a reference, EF fails creating the database schema with an DbUpdateException, whose error message is along the lines of "Unable to determine the principal end of (constraint name). Multiple added entities may have the same primary key."

I can solve the problem by not having Video reference Category (or by not having Article reference Video, as in the first code shown), but that would defeat the generic purpose of the Category class and force me to maintain ArticleCategories, VideoCategories, etc.

To be perfectly clear what I need, here is the schema I'd like to end up with (note: the CategoryID in Video should not be nullable, contrary to the image):

[image: Database diagram]

How do I define such a relationship using code-first fluent notation?

Comment: Your question is missing `Video` class and mapping which caused the error.

Comment: Updated post with the missing links (recreated from memory, as I've moved on - working on a deadline here). There's nothing fancy about the added code though.

Comment: Do you want to maintain the one to one relation ship for Article and Video? If it so then make the videoid as the primary key in article

Comment: Video is not a prerequisite for having an Article and I want to be able to create them independently and only link them at a later time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce the issue, your configs are just fine (I'm using automatic migrations here).

Can you add the exact error it gives to you?

Anyway, that's my exact code: https://gist.github.com/1961958

And that's the generated SQL from Update-Database: https://gist.github.com/1961961

EDIT: ops, I didn't see the exact same answer from @BalazsTihanyi, sorry.

Comment: I'll reproduce it tomorrow and post the error. FWIW I'm using EF 4.3.

Comment: I am able to reproduce both the error and the working code, so obviously I must be doing something differently or have some other code that causes the problem. I'll accept your answer to this question and post a new one once I figure out what is causing the problem.

Comment: FYI, the specific error I get is: "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: Unable to determine the principal end of the 'MF.Data.Infrastructure.Context.Video_Category' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key. ---> System.Data.UpdateException: Unable to determine the principal end of the 'MF.Data.Infrastructure.Context.Video_Category' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key."

Comment: I'm pretty sure that exception have something to do with the data already existing in the db. In these cases, i always end up deleting the db (if I'm working in a non-production code) or writing my own migration. Maybe it can be useful to inspect, inside the DbUpdateException, the Entries property to see which objects  are causing the problem.

Comment: I am testing this with a unit test that deletes and creates the database, so doubt this has anything to do with it. But I'll add a link to my new question in the comments once I narrow it down a bit.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Totally my own fault - my helper method was also running the database populate commands and they weren't properly setting the required FK relation, which caused the error but made it look like creation was failing. Thanks for helping!

Comment: (I knew it was the helper! I swear! It sounded too suspicious from the beginning!) In the end, i didn't helped much :S but you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Strange, but this is all working for me. I can't reproduce the error from your submitted code.
What if you try to recreate your tables from migration 0?

Comment: I'll reproduce it tomorrow and let you know. Weird.